# “Missing $ inserted” in included .tex file via \input

Tags: input, input-encodings, spanish

I've included a .tex file by using `\input` macro, but the problem comes when I use special characters (because I'm writing in Spanish, I use `á`, `é`, and characters like that).

I can use those caracters without any problem in the parent file (I have the spanish package declared), but not in the included file.

For that reason I get "Missing $ inserted" error.

Comment: Normally there should be no problem - if the tex-file you input use the same encoding as the parent file.

Comment: Can it be an issue related to TexLive?

Comment: No. Whatever your problem is, it is related to your actual document(s). Try to make a complete example that demonstrates your problem, put the file in a zip-file and upload them somewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.  
Check if both files are saved using the same encoding. Most likely the sub-file is in a different one.

Comment: Try to use the package `grffile`.

Comment: Yes @MartinScharrer it was a file encodings issue. I included several files, and some of them had different encodings. It is working now with all file encodings set to UTF-8.

Thanks for all the answers

Comment: @NahuelGarbezza: I posted it as an answer. Please consider accepting it, so that the thread can be properly concluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely be caused by different file encodings. Check if all files use the same encoding and use `\usepackage[<encoding>]{inputenc}`, where the `<encoding>` can be e.g. `utf8`.