# \input problem 'missing $' 'extra }'

Tags: errors, input

I'm writing my thesis and I'm stuck on a problem

```
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[brazil]{babel}

 \input{./inc/Intro/intro.tex}
```

When compiling I get tons of "Missing $", "Missing {", "Extra }"
If I insert my text manually it works

The funny thing I just noticed is that the compiler acuses error in the main file(TCC.tex), not in the one I'm trying to input. But the lines that have "errors" are equivalent to the ones in intro.tex file

```
E: /Users/Rafael/Dropbox/Poli/13 Semestre/TCC/Relatório/Latex/modelo_poli/TCC.tex:3 Missing $ inserted ...ventualmente, suprir uma carência tecnoló
E: /Users/Rafael/Dropbox/Poli/13 Semestre/TCC/Relatório/Latex/modelo_poli/TCC.tex:3 Extra }, or forgotten $ ...ventualmente, suprir uma carência tecnoló
E: /Users/Rafael/Dropbox/Poli/13 Semestre/TCC/Relatório/Latex/modelo_poli/TCC.tex:4 Missing $ inserted
E: /Users/Rafael/Dropbox/Poli/13 Semestre/TCC/Relatório/Latex/modelo_poli/TCC.tex:5 Missing $ inserted ... do projeto, nosso objetivo é ter o protó
E: /Users/Rafael/Dropbox/Poli/13 Semestre/TCC/Relatório/Latex/modelo_poli/TCC.tex:5 Extra }, or forgotten $ ... do projeto, nosso objetivo é ter o protó
```

There is another question very similar to mine at: [tabular, siunitx and input - `Extra }, or forgotten $.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/tabular-siunitx-and-input-extra-or-forgotten)

But I couldn't really bring this to my problem. I also don't understand what the solution of "using an additional column" is exactly

I also found this topic: [“Missing $ inserted” in included .tex file via \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39479/missing-inserted-in-included-tex-file-via-input)

And indeed the encoding of the files was different but now I set both to UTF-8...

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for portuguese?

Comment: I did and I got  
    E: /Users/Rafael/Dropbox/Poli/13 Semestre/TCC/Relatório/Latex/modelo_poli/TCC.tex:2 Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:e not set up for use with LaTeX ...chapter}{Lista de Ilustraes}{}{chapter.0}

Comment: What is contained in `intro.tex`?

Comment: Try removing accents in your folder names

Comment: I don't know why, but in my experience, spaces and accents are not welcome on the names of directories and file names used by latex compiler... I suggest you to manage your project on E:/myTCC/ . E Boa Sorte!! :)

Comment: @Rafael the specified encoding has to match the act ual encoding in the file if you chaneg from `[utf8[` to `[latin1]` you need to save the file in the appropriate encoding. You say you set the file encoding to utf8 but your code fragment says latin1 ?

Comment: Also, `\input{inc/Intro/intro}`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it worked!

I did two things here:

1. I really had to fix the encoding, but I chose Western (Windows 1252).
   I'm not pretty sure why it worked with Western and not with UTF8, but I'm using a model made by someone else so I just used his settings
2. I took the spaces and accents from the directories and filenames

Thanks for the help everybody!